# Why doesn't Stack allow relative paths?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm working on a library which depends on an external C library, and would like to bundle the headers and lib files with my project. The `stack.yaml` file requires all paths to be absolute, which is clearly not ideal for this purpose.

As per @adamse's request, here is my `stack.yaml`:

```
flags: {}

extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- ALUT-2.4.0.2
- OpenAL-1.7.0.4
resolver: lts-7.2
extra-lib-dirs:
- './dependencies/freealut/admin/VisualStudio6/alut/x64/Release'
- './dependencies/openal-soft-1.16.0-bin/openal-soft-1.16.0-bin/libs/Win64'
```

and the error message:

```
Could not parse 'C:\Users\Jonatan\Desktop\Haskell\modules\AbbeyRoad\stack.yaml':
Aeson exception:
Error in $['extra-lib-dirs'][0]: failed to parse field 'extra-lib-dirs': InvalidAbsDir "./dependencies/freealut/admin/VisualStudio6/alut/x64/Release"
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
```

`.cabal`:

```
  extra-libraries:     OpenAL32, alut
  extra-lib-dirs:      ./dependencies/freealut/admin/VisualStudio6/alut/x64/Release, ./dependencies/openal-soft-1.16.0-bin/openal-soft-1.16.0-bin/libs/Win64
```

Comment: Could you share your `stack.yaml` and any error messages you get?

Comment: Done. Although I got the impression that you simply *cannot* use relative paths right now, hence the title.

Comment: FYI, [the docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/latest/yaml_configuration/) mention that the path *should* be absolute.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the `extra-lib-dirs` in a .cabal file instead?

Comment: Doesn't work. It complains about a missing library (OpenAL32). I've added the relevant portion from my .cabal file

Comment: @adamse Seems like both `Cabal` and `Stack` restrict you to using absolute paths, which leads to my original question...